# Every $1$-manifold is orientable

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

How to prove that every $1$-manifold is orientable?

Can I use Zorn's Lemma and produce a maximal orientable manifold  that will have to be all M?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest just to list them?

Answer (score 4):

There are two connected 1-dimensional manifolds. The circle and the real line. Both are obviously orientable because the volume forms $d\theta$ and $dx$ are non-vanishing.

Comment: @t.b. thanks. Obviously the union of two orientable manifolds is orientable

Comment: Of course, hence "quibble" :) For the sake of completeness: A detailed proof of the classification of $1$-manifolds from first principles is given in an appendix to Milnor's *[Topology from the differentiable viewpoint](http://books.google.com/books?id=BaQYYJp84cYC)*.

Comment: I was looking for a direct proof but I will see if I can adapt.

Comment: You can start with a chart, and see if you can extend $\frac{d}{dx}$ to a vector field in the whole manifold.